# Time-based quota for serving files via Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, quota

Is there a way to make nginx stop serving files after some amount of traffic has happened in a given period of time? Something like - if the server served more than 1G in the last day, stop serving. By stop I preferably mean no response at all (as if it were stopped completely), but other options, such as connection refused, slow down or serve a specific HTTP response code (e.g. 503) or similar, are OK, too.